Is there any way to check if a KeyValuePair<string, int> contains a specific Key in a Dictionary in one line?
In my code I have a Dictionary, which at first was just <string, int>. However, I needed a way for two things with the same string to be separate elements in the Dictionary, so I made the Key int and the Value a KeyValuePair<string, int>.
Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<string, int>>()
The problem is, I need to check if a specific string exists in the Dictionary, preferably without the use of a for/foreach loop. Using Dictionary.ContainsValue I could check for a KeyValuePair, but the int in the KeyValuePair isn't specified and would need to be if I used ContainsValue.
Is there any way to check if the Dictionary contains a KeyValuePair with a specific Key in one line?
If anyone has any other fixes for the problem that'd be great too.
Thanks in advance!

Sounds like the key of your dictionary is on the wrong thing...

No that's the thing; the Key used to be the string, but I need to be able to have the same string multiple times, so I made the Key an int to make it unique

Maybe you need a Lookup instead?

IMHO Dictionary<string, HashSet<int>> or something. You still want to lookup the string key right?

+1 that Dictionary no longer looks like an adequate data structure for your needs. You have gone from needing a unique string (essentially indexed value) to a structure where the string can be duplicated. You could just as easily use a List<KeyValuePair<string,int>> now.
However yes you can still check the values of the dictionary:
// Does a string exist: 
var exists = myDictionary.Values.Any(x => x.Key == myString);

// Values with string: 
var keyValues = myDictionary.Values.Where(x => x.Key == myString);

Unless you still have code that indexes the dictionary by the unique ID then there is no point continuing to use a dictionary.

I don't seem to be able to use Where or Any and can't find anything about it on Google either. I'll probably use the List instead. Thanks!

They are extensions in System.Linq and should work fine against the Dictionary.Values set (not the Dictionary itself though). But yeah, a List is arguably more suitable.

Sounds like you want a dictionary of dictionaries; which (I find) comes up quite frequently in team and multi-player scenarios; e.g.
// ... playerDic = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>>();
// ... propertyDic = new Dictionary<string, int>();

int player = 1;
string property = "Lives";

propertyDic[ property ] = 9;
playerDic[ player ] = propertyDic;

// ...
var playerLives = playerDic.Contains( player ) ? 
   playerDic[ player ].Contains( property ) ?
   playerDic[ player ][ property ] : 0;  // or some other default.

Normally you would "prime" these dictionaries with players (on start and connect) so you wouldn't need to do a "contains player" check everytime.
